# Open a specific page of a pdf file using c sharp

Tags: c#

My requirement is as : we have to open a PDF file in new tab. file is opened in new tab successfully, but we want to open 5th page instead-of 1st page. can we achieve it by using c sharp.

My code is below to open pdf in new tab:

```
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            string fileName = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(yderInfo, System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8).Replace("+", " ");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; attachment;filename*=UTF-8''" + fileName + ".pdf");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.GetBuffer().Length);               
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: Forever? You expect that file to open at page 5 forever? You realize you are simply sending a pdf file and hoping the browser will show it, right? They might use something else to open it.

Comment: Adding e.g. `#page=5` to the PDF URL shall open at page 5 on any browser

Answer (score 0):

Try using **PDF.js(https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)** to display your doc in browser and use the below property to set the page.

```
PDFView.initialBookmark = "page=5";
```